# django-s3direct file upload issue

Tags: django, django-admin

Let me explain you the situation in brief:

I am working on a django project in which I am trying to add a functionality wherein, I can upload a file directly to S3 from django-admin. For this purpose, I am using django-s3direct package. I have done all the setup as stated in the documentation. The problem I am facing is, whenever I select a file to upload, the progress-bar in the admin shows no progress and the following is the output on commandline:

```
POST /s3direct/get_aws_v4_signature/ HTTP/1.1" 200 64
```

Requesting your help at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. The problem occurred because boto does not support some regions, and my region was one of them. I changed the region and everything works smoothly now.

Comment: link to docs on this? regions that didn't work, and ones that did?